# HIVE SQL: Select rows whose values contain string in a column

Tags: sql, string, hive

I want to select rows whose values contain a string in a column. 
For example, I want to select all rows whose values contain a **string** `'123'` in the **column** `'app'`. 
**table:**

```
app         id
123helper   xdas
323helper   fafd
2123helper  dsaa
3123helper  fafd
md5321      asdx
md5123      dsad
```

**result:**

```
app         id
123helper   xdas
2123helper  dsaa
3123helper  fafd
md5123      dsad
```

I am not familiar with SQL query.
Could anyone help me? .
Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a number of ways:

**like:**

```
select * from table
where app like '%123%'
```

**rlike:**

```
...
where app rlike '123'
```

**instr:**

```
...
where instr(app, '123')>0
```

**locate:**

```
...
where  locate('123', app)>0
```

Invent your own way.

Read manual: [String Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) and [Operators](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following using `like`

```
select
  *
from yourTable
where app like '%123%'
```

Output:

```
| app        | id   |
| ---------- | ---- |
| 123helper  | xdas |
| 2123helper | dsaa |
| 3123helper | fafd |
| md5123     | dsad |
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below query,

```
select app, id from table where app like '%123%';
```

Below are few additional information,

```
like '123%' --> Starts with 123
like '%123' --> Ends with 123
like '%123%'--> Contains 123 anywhere in the string
```